# Java web start doesn't work after java version 7u45 (NPE)

Tags: java, glassfish, java-web-start

Our java application is launchend via java web start (with glassfish 4.0). After updating to java 7u45, it doesn't work anymore. Here is the error message:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.io.StringReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.glassfish.appclient.client.JWSAppClientContainerMain.insertMaskingLoader(JWSAppClientContainerMain.java:186)
at org.glassfish.appclient.client.JWSAppClientContainerMain.main(JWSAppClientContainerMain.java:132)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeApplication(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.executeMainClass(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.doLaunchApp(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javaws.Launcher.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

This happens right after the download finished. After a quick look into the GF source file, it seems that the property `loader.config` is not defined as the second line throws the NPE:

```
final String loaderConfig = System.getProperty("loader.config");
StringReader sr = new StringReader(loaderConfig);
```

**EDIT** 
The above two code lines where the NPE happens is Glassfish code, from the Class `JWSAppClientContainerMain` in the jar `gf-client-module.jar`. It worked until java update 45.

Comment: what is the value of loaderConfig?

Answer (score 1):

As of Update 45, JavaWebstart will no longer pass insecure properties to your application. All properties that are not prefixed with `jnlp` or `javaws` are considered insecure.

You either need to change `loader.config` to `jnlp.loader.config` (both in the JNLP as well as your java code), or you need to sign the JNLP (place an exact copy of your JNLP in 
`JNLP-INF/APPLICATION.JNLP` inside your jar and sign the jar).

According to [this OpenJDK Bugreport](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8023821?focusedCommentId=13377692&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3acomment-tabpanel#comment-13377692) this is an intentional change to resolve a security 
vulnerability

Comment: Shouldn't *"..your you need to sign the JNLP"* be *"..or your need to sign the JNLP"*.  The second makes sense, while the first ..doesn't.

Comment: I cannot change `loader.config` as it is a property from GF. But I tried to copy the JNLP into the JNLP-INF directory of the jar. However, I still get the same error.
I also deployed a sample web start application from Oracle on my Glassfish server but it results in the same error.

Comment: Did you also rename the JNLP file to `APPLICATION.JNLP` (inside the jar, in the `JNLP-INF` directory) and then sign the jar?

Comment: Yes I renamed it to `APPLICATION.JNLP`. And I think jars are automatically signed in GF. However it is self-signed as we are currently using the default certificate.

Comment: You can check if the JAR is signed by using `jarsigner.exe -verify -verbose  jarfile.jar`. You might also be running into an issue with self-signed certificates which will no longer work by default as of 7u51 - see [this oracle blog post](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/new_security_requirements_for_rias) for details

Comment: `jarsigner` tells me it is signed. I also tried it with a trusted code signing certificate, it still results in the same error. Anymore hints?

Answer (score 0):

There is no property with key "loader.config" in your system properties.that's why it returns null value to `loaderConfig`. When you pass `null` value to the `StringReader` constructor, it will throw NPE since the length method is invoked on the input Constructor argument (**null** value). Please see below

```
public StringReader(String s) {
        this.str = s;
        this.length = s.length();
    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: thanks, but the problem is, that this is glassfish intern code for java web start. The property `loader.config` is something from glassfish, and I am wondering why it is null (i.e. not set) after updating to java 7u45

Comment: @dominicp Did you try mth's answer? the link gives you the answer

Comment: May be take a look at the release notes - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/7u45-relnotes-2016950.html. It may give some idea.

Answer (score 0):

We searched a lot about this issue and luckily we found a solution that worked perfectly for us.

in our jnlp file we had:

```
<resources>
        <j2se version="1.5+"/>
        ...
</resources>
```

we have changed it in this mode:

```
<resources>
        <j2se version="1.6+" java-vm-args="-Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true"/>
        ...
</resources>
```

we found this solution here:

https://community.oracle.com/thread/2520987

Hope this may help you.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, but I still get the same NPE with the adjusted jnlp file.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is solved in [glassfish 4.1](https://java.net/jira/browse/GLASSFISH-20711), until then downgrade your java to u21 or older.